# Help with NullPointerException on API level 5

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-tabhost, tabwidget, unhandled-exception

I developed my application using API level 8 but the minimum SDK is 3. I did most of the testing on an emulator running 8 and my DroidX as well as some friends phones. No problems thus far. It should also be known that I did not use any API's above Level 3, and the Tab Layout was almost and exact copy of the example provided by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). So.... when running on an emulator with level 5 API I get the following error and I have no clue where it's coming from except for the references to TabWidget.

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw(TabWidget.java:206)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1524)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1524)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1524)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6539)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1526)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1256)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6539)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1348)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1113)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1632)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, parent.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("browse").setIndicator("Browse",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_browse))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, bookmarks.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("bookmarks").setIndicator("Bookmarks",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_bookmarks))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, search.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("search").setIndicator("Search",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_search))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and format code to understand the problem better?

Comment: sorry about that and thanks EboMike for doing that for me.

Comment: I am having the same problem...could this be a possible bug in the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no code to work with, it is difficult to give you much advice.

- If you are not using `TabActivity`, make sure you call `setup()` on your `TabHost` before doing anything else with it.
- Since the exception is coming from `TabWidget`, try temporarily simplifying your tab indicators and see if that helps localize or clear up the problem.

Comment: CommonsWare, I always hope to see one of your responses. I have updated the answer to include the code. It's pretty simple and I have tried a bunch of stuff with no luck. I'm wonder though, where are the resources supposed to be located on api 5? In Drawable or is drawable-ldpi, etc. ok?

Comment: I forgot, I am using TabActivity

Comment: @Michael Little: Well, your code seems fairly straightforward. For a somewhat older API level like 5, you might want to try copying a set of drawables into `res/drawable/` and see if that helps. In theory, Android is supposed to find some likely candidate drawable if it cannot find one for the specific screen density, then scale it up or down. However, I do not know if that logic existed or perhaps had hiccups back in API 5. But I think you are on the right track --some drawable resource may not be resolving. You could also temporarily remove the icons and see what that yields.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have spent some time looking into this and so far the problem does not exist on 4 or 8 but fails on 3,5,6 and 7. I have narrowed it down to a problem with those api levels not liking other interface objects being displayed before the tabs. I have some stuff that needs to happen before the tabs appear and I think I'm going to have to rework this so it plays nice.

Comment: That appears to be what the problem was. I created an activity group and display a dummy layout to handle my utilities and then, when those are complete, I display the tabhost. This works on 7 so I'm going to test is on the others now.

Comment: I tried to do something similar because I also have things that need to be loaded before displaying the tabs.  I created a dummy layout as well however, I still am receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2):

My tabhost was showing nullPointer exception for 2.1 updated at the time when i kept it in linearLayout,but when i tried Relative layout it workes fine .
so might be this change help u if stucking in same situation .

Comment: I tried this and it works, no NPE any more, but the webview in my tab didn't show when I use RelativeLayout.. So it remains a question..